# Define a COM pointer as a private member in C++?

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers, private-members

I am wondering how I can define a COM pointer as a private member. Here is what I want to do:

in h file:

```
MCLControlPtr _mcSwitch;  //MCLControPtr is "_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_MCLControlClass, __uuidof(_MCLControlClass));"
```

in cpp constructor file

```
ThorDetectorSwitch::ThorDetectorSwitch() 
{
     _mcSwitch = new MCLControlPtr _mcSwitch(__uuidof(MCLControlClass));

    _deviceDetected = FALSE;
}
```

but of course it does not allow me to build because the syntax is not right.

I am wondering how I can do what I want to do with the right syntax? Basically initilize a COM smart pointer in constructor? I also do NOT want to use initilization list as well. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Anyone has any idea? This is really bothering me for days.

Comment: What problem could one possibly have with an initialization list?

Comment: @chris I got "CoInitialize has not been called" expcetion, so I want to call CoInitialize(NULL) in front of _mcSwitch(__uuidof(MCLControlClass));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your head file

```
COMInterface *_comInterface;
```

In your cpp file

```
COMInterfacePtr comSmartPtr;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(see reference for stuff inside here);
_comInterface = comSmartPtr;
```